# Is Hartree-Fock energy minimisation an iterative or a Lagrange undetermined process?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, computational-physics, quantum-chemistry

Suppose the following is about a quantum system of N electrons.

1. In the canonical Hartree-Fock method, the goal is to find single - electron orbitals $\phi_{1}, ...,\phi_{N}$ such that $\langle \psi_{HF} | \hat{H} | \psi_{HF} \rangle = E_{HF, min}$ where $\psi_{HF} = \psi_{HF}(\phi_{1}, ..., \phi_{N})$.
2. energy minimisation involving Lagrange undetermined multiplier
3. The following is arrived at: $\hat{F}\phi_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^{N}\epsilon_{ij}\phi_{j}(r_{1})$
   where $\epsilon_{ij}$ is the Lagrange multiplier matrix, $\hat{F}$ the Fock operator and $\phi$ being a single - electron spatial orbital.
4. Then choose another set of single -electron spatial orbital $\phi_{i} = \bar{\phi_{j}}T_{ji}$ which diagonalise $\epsilon_{ij}$.
   This gives $\hat{F}\bar{\phi_{i}}(r_{1}) = \epsilon_{i}\bar{\phi_{i}}(r_{1})$. This is an eigenvector equation and for a system of $N$ electrons, there are $N$ coupled eigenvector equations, each eigenvector equation corresponding to the $i$ electron.

Here's my question:

1. do we solve the the set of $N$ coupled eigenvector equation once (must be done iteratively in general) and call it a day
   or
2. do we solve the $N$ coupled eigenvector equation once, plug it back into 4. This entire step is then repeated a large number of times so that at the end of some large iteration the set of $N$ single - electron spatial orbital for $\psi_{HF}$ yields the minimal energy of the system?

I apologise for what seems like a trivial question but having been exposed to optimisation process in computer science, I find it helps for me to clarify the confusion.

Comment: The result for the integrity-differential equation is derived using Lagrange multipliers and the equation is solved iteratively on a computer.

Comment: While it is perfectly fine to ask this question here, I suppose that Matter Modeling SE indeed is the better place to ask these kind of questions.